# Problem formatting spreadsheets in R, how can I read and write to tables using R?

Tags: r, spreadsheet

I'm working with R for the first time for a class in college. To preface this: I don't know enough to know what I don't know, so I'm sorry if this question has been asked before. I am trying to predict the results of the Texas state house elections in 2020, and I think the best prior for that is the results of the 2018 state house elections. There are 150 races, so I can't bare to input them all by hand, but I can't find any spreadsheet that has data formatted how I want it. I want it in a pretty standard table format:
[My desired table format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VKtbF.png). However, the table from the Secretary of state I have looks like the following:
[Gross ugly table.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hA4Vo.png)

I wrote some psuedo  code:
 Here's the Psuedo Code, basically we want to construct a new CSV:

'''%First, we want to find a district, the house races are always preceded by a line of dashes, so I will need a function like this:

```
Create a New CSV;
for(x=1; x<151 ; x +=1){
    Assign x to the cell under the district number cloumn;
    Find "---------------" ;
    Go down one line;
    Go over two lines;

% We should now be in the third column and now want to read in which party got how many votes. The number of parties is not consistant, so we need to account for uncontested races, libertarians, greens, and write ins. I want totals for Republicans, Democrats, and Other.

while(cell is not empty){
    Party <- function which reads cell (but I want to read a string);
    go right one column;
    Votes <- function which reads cell (but I want to read an integer);
    if(Party = Rep){
        put this data in place in new CSV;
    else if (Party = Dem)
        put this data in place in new CSV;
    else
        OtherVote += Votes;
    };
};
Assign OtherVote to the column for other party;
OtherVote <- 0;

%Now I want to assign 0 to null cells (ones where no rep, or no Dem, or no other party contested

read through single row 4 spaces, if its null assign it 0;
Party <- null
};'''
```

But I don't know enough to google what to do! Here's what I need help with: Can I create a new CSV in Rstudio, how? How can I read specific cells in a table,  hopefully indexing? Lastly, how do I write to a table in R. Any help is appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: Can you share a link to the original data, please.

Answer (score 0):

> Can I create a new CSV in Rstudio, how?

Yes you can. Use the "write.csv" function.

`write.csv(df, file = "df.csv")` #see help for more information.

> How can I read specific cells in a table?

Use the brackets after df,example below.

```
df <- data.frame(x = c(1,2,3),  y = c("A","B","C"), z = c(15,25,35))

df[1,1]

#[1] 1

df[1,1:2]

#  x y
#1 1 A
```

> How do I write to a table in R?

If you want to write a table in xlsx use the function `write.xlsx` from `openxlsx` package.

Answer (score 0):

[Wikipedia seems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2018_United_States_House_of_Representatives_elections_in_Texas) to have a table that is closer to the format you are looking for.
In order to get to the table you are looking for we need a few steps:

1. Download data from Wikipedia and extract table.
2. Clean up table.
3. Select columns.
4. Calculate margins.

#### 1. Download data from wikipedia and extract table.

The `rvest` table helps with downloading and parsing websites into R objects.
First we download the HTML of the whole website.

```
library(dplyr)
library(rvest)
wiki_html <-
  read_html(
    "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2018_United_States_House_of_Representatives_elections_in_Texas"
  )
```

There are a few ways to get a specific object from an HTML file in this case
I dedided to look for the table that has the class name “wikitable plainrowheaders sortable”,
as I learned from inspecting the code, that the only table with that class is
the one we want to extract.

```
library(purrr)
html_nodes(wiki_html, "table") %>%
  map_lgl( ~ html_attr(., "class") == "wikitable plainrowheaders sortable") %>%
  which()
#> [1] 20
```

Then we can select table number 20 and convert it to a dataframe with `html_table()`

```
raw_table <-
  html_nodes(wiki_html, "table")[[20]] %>%
  html_table(fill = TRUE)
```

#### 2.  Clean up table.

The table has duplicated names, we can change that by using `as_tibble()` and its `.name_repair` argument. We then use`dplyr::select()` to get the columns. Furthermore we use`dplyr::filter()` to delete the first two rows, that have "District" as a value in the`District`column. Now the columns are still `characters`
vectors, but we need them to be `numeric`, therefore we first delete commas from
all columns and then transform columns 2 to 4 to numeric.

```
clean_table <-
  raw_table %>%
  as_tibble(.name_repair = "unique") %>%
  filter(District != "District") %>%
  mutate_all( ~ gsub(",", "", .)) %>%
  mutate_at(2:4, as.numeric)
```

#### 3.  Select columns and 4. Calculate margins.

We use `dplyr::select()` to select the columns you are interested in and give them more helpful names.
Finally we calculate the margin between democratic and republican votes by first adding up there votes
as `total_votes` and then dividing the difference by `total_votes`.

```
clean_table %>%
  select(District,
         RepVote = Republican...2,
         DemVote = Democratic...4,
         OthVote = Others...6) %>%
  mutate(
    total_votes = RepVote + DemVote,
    margin = abs(RepVote - DemVote) / total_votes * 100
  )
#> # A tibble: 37 x 6
#>    District    RepVote DemVote OthVote total_votes margin
#>    <chr>         <dbl>   <dbl> <chr>         <dbl>  <dbl>
#>  1 District 1   168165   61263 3292         229428  46.6 
#>  2 District 2   139188  119992 4212         259180   7.41
#>  3 District 3   169520  138234 4604         307754  10.2 
#>  4 District 4   188667   57400 3178         246067  53.3 
#>  5 District 5   130617   78666 224          209283  24.8 
#>  6 District 6   135961  116350 3731         252311   7.77
#>  7 District 7   115642  127959 0            243601   5.06
#>  8 District 8   200619   67930 4621         268549  49.4 
#>  9 District 9        0  136256 16745        136256 100   
#> 10 District 10  157166  144034 6627         301200   4.36
#> # … with 27 more rows
```

Edit: In case you want to go with the data provided by the state, it looks to me as if the data you are looking for is in the first, third and fourth column. So what you want to do is.

(All the code below is not tested, as I do not have the original data.)

read data into R

```
library(readr)
   tx18 <- read_csv("filename.csv")
```

select relevant columns

```
tx18 <- tx18 %>%
        select(c(1,3,4))
```

clean table

```
tx18 <- tx18 %>%
        filter(!is.na(X3),
               X3 != "Party",
               X3 != "Race Total")
```

Group and summarize data by party

```
tx18 <- tx18 %>% 
  group_by(X3) %>%
  summarise(votes = sum(X3))
```

Pivot/ Reshape data to wide format

```
tx18 %>$ 
      pivot_wider(names_from = X3,
                  values_from = votes)
```

After this you could then calculate the margin similarly as I did with the Wikipedia data.